# PHP: Find number in a string and add space between each number

Tags: php

i have a example string: "hi account 1234, your order is 5678". 
How can i detect number in string and add space between each number, mean the result must: "hi account 1 2 3 4, your order is 5 6 7 8"
I need to add that space to work with google tts :(

Comment: Use a regular expression to find the number. Split the number into an array, and use `implode()` to insert spaces between the elements. Then replace this back into the original string. This can all be done in `preg_replace_callback()`.

Comment: Hopefully that's enough to get you going -- we're not going to write it for you.

Comment: `\d` is a number in regex. I think just `preg_replace` would work for you.

Comment: If you don't mind an extra space after the last digit, you can just replace every digit with the digit followed by space. That's much simpler.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  You'll get a better response if you show that you've made some effort, eg show us what you've tried, why you tried that, describe what happens, etc. We're here bcs we want to help, but SO isn't a code-writing service.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
preg_replace('/\d/', '$0 ', 'hi account 1234, your order is 5678');
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks all,
i have a simple code that completed this case:

```
$phrase  = "'hi account 1234, your order is 5678";
$search = ["1", "2", "3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0"];
$replace = ["1 ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 ", "6 ", "7 ", "8 ", "9 ", "0 "];
$newPhrase = str_replace($search, $replace, $phrase);
```

tks for all your help